# cannot resolve hostname if ethernet is disabled

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

I have a small home network with a media server running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. It has both ethernet and wifi connections enabled and working.

I access the Ubuntu box it using remote desktop from a Mac on the same network. I also can access some of the shared files on the media server in the network area of MacOS Finder.

These connections work just fine when just the ethernet connection is enabled, or when both ethernet and wifi are enabled.

Oddly, if I disable the ethernet connection, RDP fails to connect. Shared folders on the Ubuntu box also fail to appear on the Mac.

Can anyone suggest why these functions would stop working when WiFi is the only network connection?

Comment: Please check your router settings as what you describe suggests WiFi isolation. Nothing to do with Ubuntu or MacOS.

Comment: Also check the settings in macOS System Preferences -> Network ->  WiFi.

Comment: I have Google Wifi. it doesn't support isolation. I also have the guest network disabled.